# Scale and Translate an ImageView Programatically

Tags: android, animation

I have a `ImageView` of **Face**. I used `Google Vision Library` to find **Eyes Landmark** `(cx,cy)`. Now I want to `Scale` the `ImageView` so that the **Eyes** will be in focus and `Translate` it accordigly.

What will be the easiest possible way to do this than using `zoom_animation.xml`

**I tried this but not getting proper result**

```
Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
float[] values = new float[9];
m.getValues(values);
float xxx = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
float yyy = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
float www = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] * imageView.getWidth();
float hhh = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] * imageView.getHeight();

//cx and cy are eye positions
imageView.setScale(1.5f, cx - www / 2, cy - yyy / 2, false);
```

I read the documentation and find `setScale()` accept these parameters:

`setScale(float scale, float focalX, float focalY, boolean animate)`

**I am wondering how should I implement** `focalX and focalY` **or is there any way so I can convert** `cx, cy` **into** `focalX, focalY` **??**

**Thank You In Advance**